# Syntax Error: Encountered "(" at line 2, column 14

Tags: php, sql, netbeans

I'm executing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE following (
    id        int(255) auto_increment not null,
    user      int(255),
    followed  int(255),
    CONSTRAINT pk_following PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_following_users FOREIGN KEY (user), references users(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_followed FOREIGN KEY (followed), references users(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDb;
```

And I get the following error: [Exception, Error code 30.000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax Error: Encountered "(" at line 2, column 14.

Answer (score 0):

`int(255)`.  That's weird.  Just do:

```
CREATE TABLE following (
    id        int auto_increment not null,
    user      int,
    followed  int,
    CONSTRAINT pk_following PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_following_users FOREIGN KEY (user) references users(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_followed FOREIGN KEY (followed) references users(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDb;
```

I also removed the unnecessary commas in the `foreign key` definition.